# Adding scaled number

Tags: summation, arithmetic, normed-spaces

Assume that I have 3 scaled variables: $a$, $b$ and $c$. I would like to write a formula to get the sum of all these variables. Currently, what I have is as follows:

$$x = \left(\frac{1}{1 + \textrm{a}}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{1 + \textrm{b}}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{1 + \textrm{c}}\right)$$

This looks weird and I am not sure if there is any ways to simplify this.
Thanks.

Comment: What are they scaled to?  Presumably you want the sum to be in some specific range.  What is it?  Note that if $a,b,c$ are scaled to $[0,1]$ the sum could be as large as $3$ and it increases when any given variable decreases, so it doesn't look like a sum.

Comment: The sum is not limited to any ranges. I just want to make sure these three variables do not cause problems due to huge differences between them. For example, a = 100 and c = 1. In this case, the sum does not equally represent the value for these variables.

Comment: Your sum will not cause any problems as long as none of them can be $-1$.  You haven't described what you want the sum to do, so we can't help with that.

Comment: the sum is actually a score which I intended to assign to a Twitter user, where a = number of friends, b = number of followers and c = number of tweets. I would like to have each variables equally contributed to the sum. Hope it is clear. @RossMillikan, do you think it is the right way for me to use such equation?

Comment: There are lots of formulas.  You need to decide what you are trying to do, then find a formula that does that.  For this one the score will be dominated by the smallest of $a,b,c$ and the other two will not matter much.  That doesn't seem reasonable to me.  You mentioned scaling the variables but it doesn't sound like you have done so.  If people tend to have ten times more friends than followers and send $20$ times more tweets than they have followers you might use $\frac a{10}+b+\frac c{20}$ as a first try.

Comment: do you have any recommended function to scaled the variable, separately? i thought $ \frac{1}{1 + x} $ is considered as scaling the variable $ x $? sorry i am new in this.

Comment: I think of scaling as multiplying by a constant to make the range be what you want.  That is what I did in my suggestion, basically trying to make the range of each variable the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is quite clear.  You could write it as $$\frac {(1+a)(1+b)+(1+b)(1+c)+(1+a)(1+c)}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}$$
but that doesn't look simpler to me.  You could then expand out the numerator or denominator but I don't think that helps anything, either.

Comment: The numerator is missing $2x+2y+2x+3$.